# fire a popup when ApplicationBarMenuItem clicked

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, application-bar

I need to fire a popup when `ApplicationBarMenuItem` clicked. but nothing happen when I click `MenuItem`. here is my code;

```
<shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
     <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Go by date" Click="GoByDate_Click" />
</shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>


private void GoByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Popup popup = new Popup();
     popup.Height = 480;
     popup.Width = 480;
     popup.VerticalOffset = 100;
     DatePopupControl datePopup = new DatePopupControl(); // just a user control comes when add new
     popup.Child = datePopup;
     popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your **DatePopupControl**, because your code worked fine for my own test control. Can you provide DatePopupControl source code?

Alright, let me try to guess. My first theory is: there is nothing to show in this popup.
For example, if you add a userControl, which has only **Grid** tag inside without anything, you *will* see in the editor in Visual Studio, but it *won't* be visible as a popup child. But if you add a single textblock, it will be.